# Is there a plugin for applying discounts on certain bank credit cards in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, discount

I would like to know if there is a plugin for applying discounts on the sub total when a certain bank credit card is being used for transaction. I am planning to connect different banks to my webstore. When a customer is purchasing a product, he/she can enter their valid credit card of the specified bank to check if they can use the discount on the sub total.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly complicated request and can change across regions and banks. 
This module does not exist in Magento Connect (or at least I can find one). You will have to make this functionality via custom module that you install in your Magento store.

Comment: Yes. I do feel its a complicated one. But there is a website that has done this feature. Http://uae.voxcinemas.com . Its a movie booking portal. When a customer books his ticket, he has the option to select his bank credit card and check if its a valid one that can be applied as a discount on the cart. So my idea Is also the same.

Comment: I am not saying it can't be done, I am saying you will have to make it. What makes you think they didn't customize this functionality on their own?

Comment: Yes you are right. It must be a custom made one. Most of the third party stores doesnt have this type of plugin.